# How Load asset only once laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How Load asset only once. if i open dashboard, all asset will be load and then i open other page, not load asset second time..

how to make load asset only once in blade template?

ex:

template.blade.php

```
@yield('css') 
@yield('js')
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
@section('css')
//some code here
@endsection
```

group.blade.php

```
@section('css')
//some code here
@endsection
```

any help me?
thanks

Comment: Well, in `dashboard.blade.php` you define the `css` section, in `group.blade.php` you define a **different** `css` section. You only load assets you've defined in a single file. If you want assets to load for all files you need to define them in `template.blade.php` .

Comment: @apokryfos, i hope asset not loaded again when i access group and then dashboard.... i hope asset loaded at the beginning application opened

Comment: @apokryfos, you have example for AJAX + laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how the HTTP protocol works. The HTTP protocol is stateless, meaning it does not *remember* that a user visited the `dashboard` before they visited `group`.

The only assurance you have is that when a user visits the dashboard the CSS of the dashboard will be cached so subsequent requests for them will load them from the cache and not from the webserver.

However you must assume that a user could visit `group` first so **all** required CSS for group must be included in the group template, even if that means that means you'll be replicating some CSS for each page.

If you really want to load each asset only once then you should use a JavaScript library like [jquery mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) to specify different sections that are loaded via AJAX. However the how and why is way too broad a question to cover here.

Answer (score 0):

Why you loading asset with @yield? Just load it on your layouts.
For example app.blade.php which in layouts folder.

**app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheets" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}"/>
<title>title goes here</title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then load layout on any view for example dashboard

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app) //it loads all template data  from layouts(app.blade.php)
@section('content')
content for dashboard
@endsection
```

Comment: same... when i click dashboard, script in app.blade.php loaded again.... so are i click other page, script in app.blade.php loaded again.... i hope asset not loaded again...